# "signtool not compatible" Inno Setup 6

Tags: inno-setup, signtool

So i was compiling a setup file in Inno setup Version 6 when the signtool that i downloaded **(newest win sdk)**
Some random "not compatible error" Happen:

> Updating version info (SETUP.E32)
> Running Sign Tool signtool: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\arm64\signtool.exe" sign /f "C:\MY_CODE_SIGNING.PFX" /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode /p pbclisetup "C:\Users\ANGGIA AYU\Downloads\uninst.e32.tmp"
> Sign Tool command failed (Failed to execute Sign Tool command.

> Error 216: This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher). Will retry (2 tries left).
> Running Sign Tool signtool: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\arm64\signtool.exe" sign /f "C:\MY_CODE_SIGNING.PFX" /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode /p pbclisetup "C:\Users\ANGGIA AYU\Downloads\uninst.e32.tmp"
> Sign Tool command failed (Failed to execute Sign Tool command.

What did i do wrong and what caused this problem?

Comment: So are you on `arm64` architecture? Can you use that specific `signtool` binary (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\arm64\signtool.exe`) separately (out of Inno Setup)?

Comment: you mean to make another key?

Comment: No, I'm asking if you can sing any binary manually using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\arm64\signtool.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem as you, I was following an instruction and I didn't pay attention to 2 points:

1: My SDK version was not like the instruction

2: My cpu architecture is x86 (no arm64, no x64)

When I changed my path to ...\10.0.19..\x86 my problem was solved.

I hope I have helped you.

Answer (score -1):

It may be a problem with the computer system. My own computer also has this problem. I can replace my colleague's computer without this problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).